# How do I add two hexadecimal values?

Tags: mips

this is a school assignment. I've been given homework and one of the problems is to figure out the value after adding two hexadecimal values.

0x80000000 and 0xD0000000. I understand that D = 13, but I don't understand how the answer is 15, because 8 + 13 = 23? Could someone explain what I am doing wrong, and what I should do instead?

Thanks!

Comment: And `23` in base 16 (hex) is `0x17`, i.e. `1 * 16 + 7 = 23`. If you understand that `0xD = 13`, then you should understand that `0xE = 14`, `0xF = 15`, and then `0x10 = 16`, i.e. 10₁₆ = 16₁₀ and 17₁₆ = 23₁₀.

Comment: `0x80000000 + 0xD0000000` doesn't equal `0x15`. Perhaps you meant `0x8 + 0xD` (which _does_ equal `0x15`).

Comment: by the way how 8+13 = 23? am I totally thinking wrong or 8 +13 = 21?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy if you think that every digit represents a quadruple, for example

`0xDEADBEEF` = 13*16⁷+14*16⁶+10*16⁵+13*16⁴+11*16³+14*16²+14*16¹+15*16⁰.

The above hexadecimal value needs an algorithm to translate to a format the the ALU can add, for instance binary numbers.

D is 13 in decimal because D is digit number 13 if A replaces 10 and so on (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F). The position of D is 7, so the number is 13*16⁷.

We notice that it is easier to LSB if we do this, and recognize that F is 15 in hexadecimal notation and therefore the number to the left will be 15*16⁰=15.

`0xFF` therefore means 15*16¹+15*16⁰=15*16+15=255 (you can check this with a calculator).

Now the algorithm is hopefully clear.

3735928559 is the decimal value of `DEADBEEF` because ==13*16^7+14*16^6+10*16^5+13*16^4+11*16^3+14*16^2+14*16^1+15*16^0=3735928559.

Answer (score 1):

Some times I convert the hexadecimal into binary base `2` this because I feel more confident to do arithmetic with binary base `2`than hexadecimal.
In order to do so you need to arrange every hexadecimal into group of `4` bits binary number.

```
 hex   0x8 + 0xD
```

Convert to binary

```
 binary  1000 + 1101 = 10101 = 21
```

group it again as 4 bits

```
 0001 0101 = 0x15
```

I ignored if it's signed number and didn't used two's complement.